# Vue-Firebase: Updating children & writing to child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vue-component

I started working with Firebase and Vue also with VueFire and i dont understand how to update child nodes at Firebase.

I opened a firebase project and connected to it and i can push data to it.

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t35ne.png)

I made a vue component

```
 import db from '../FireBase'

  let team = db.ref('Teams');//Reference to Teams at firebase 
  let miss = db.ref().child('Teams'); //Attempt to get to the children of Teams 
  export default {
    name: "App",
    firebase: {
      Teams_loc: db.ref('Teams'),
      Mission: this.Teams_loc.child('Teams'),
    missionKey:  db.ref().child('Teams').push("").key,
    },
...
```

I manage to get the Teams from firebase and send data to it:

```
this.$firebaseRefs.Teams_loc.push({
    "test": "tester"
});
```

Which works but when i try to update the children inside

```
this.miss.push({
              "where": "am i"
            })
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
```

And when i try to update a child

```
this.$firebaseRefs.missionKey.update(arr[0]);//arr[0] is an object
```

I tried looking at quite a few places but nothing seems to do the trick.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the following you are doing an error at the second line.

```
  Teams_loc: db.ref('Teams'),
  Mission: this.Teams_loc.child('Teams'),
```

There is no child of the `Teams` node that has a key with the value `Teams.

So if you want to update an item, you first have to get its key (e.g. `-LEzOBT-mp.....`) and do as follows, as explained in the doc:

```
updateItem: function (item) { 
   // create a copy of the item
   const copy = {...item}
   // remove the .key attribute
   delete copy['.key']
   //possibly update (or add) some values of (to) the item
   this.$firebaseRefs.Teams_loc.child(item['.key']).set(copy)
}
```

Also (if I am not mistaking) doing `db.ref()` will generate an error because you have to pass a value to `ref()`.

I suggest that you study a bit more the doc and the example: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire and https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/master/examples/todo-app/index.html

---

**Update following your comment. Details on how to "know the random generated key"**

According to the documentation:

> Each record in the bound array will contain a .key property which
>   specifies the key where the record is stored. So if you have data at
>   /Teams/-LEzOBT-mp...../, the record for that data will have a .key of
>   "-LEzOBT-mp.....".

Look at this part of the doc: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire#array-bindings.

So with this you will get all the keys of the Teams object. You have now to choose the item you want to update.

You could also declare a query in your firebase object, like:

```
  firebase: { 
    team21483: this.database
            .ref('Teams')
            .orderByChild('teamCode')
            .equalTo('21483') 
  }
```

and you would get an array with only one team, the one with `TeamCode = 21483`.

The best approach, in this latest case, is to manually bind to this Firebase query with the `$bindAsArray` (or possibly the `$bindAsObject`)  instance methods, using a variable that you pass to equalTo().

Comment: I know if i could get the key it would make things easier but the problem is that i want to generate entries and delete them so im not sure how i could know the random generated key i get in firebase.

Comment: Ok i see. I guess i still have a lot to learn. Ill starting working with the guidance you gave me. Thanks a lot!